# Extracting all Hash tags and adding them to a Span in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to extract the hash tags in the following variable and replace them within  tags.

**Example:**

> var original = "Mary had a #little #lamb";

Will be replaced  as:

`var new = "Mary had a <span>#little</span> <span>#lamb</span>`

**I tried this:**

```
var new = original.replace("#","<span>");
//This also replaces the #. I need the # so this solution wont work at all
```

However that just replaces the hash with the opening span tag and the closing tag won't be added. What change should I make?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var original = "Mary had a #little #lamb";
var _new = original.replace(/#(\S*)/g,'<span>#$1</span>');
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/1och8eno/1/)

Comment: This is not the result he wants. you're missing th "#" in each span

Comment: How can I reverse this as well? As in get words between <span> and replace with #word?

Comment: `var original = _new.replace(/<span>#(\S*)<\/span>/g,'#$1');`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
"Mary had a #little #lamb".replace(/(#\w+)/ig,function(a,g){ return '<span>'+g+'</span>'})
```

Result :

```
"Mary had a <span>#little</span> <span>#lamb</span>"
```

- The replacer function can be shortcut like the other answers above.Howver I prefer to see what is actually going on.
- `a` is the  matched substring
- `g` is the first group

If they were additional groups then the function would look like :

```
function(a,g1,g2,g3....)
```

Comment: How can I reverse this as well? As in get words between <span> and replace with #word?

Answer (score 1):

you probably want something like this (depending on what can be in a hash tag):

```
var original = "Mary had a #little #lamb";
var _new = original.replace(/(#[A-Za-z]+)/g, '<span>$1</span>');
console.log(_new);
```

Comment: How can I reverse this as well? As in get words between <span> and replace with #word?